# Handlers of elements of WrapPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have dynamically created WrapPanel (_wp) with several Borders. And I need create handler to each border. How can I do it via C#?

```
        for (int k = 1; k < i+1; k++)
        {
            _b = new Border()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 5, 0),
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3),
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
                Child = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = k.ToString(),
                    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    FontSize = 28,
                }
            };
            _wp.Children.Add(_b); 
        }
```

I need Tap handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
 _b.Tap += yourHandler;
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that I need to do it during the creation of each border. So, it was a very stupid question :) Thank you!

Comment: @Max: you're welcome! In fact, the code like `Tap="handler"` in XAML gets converted into exactly the same code using `+=` (you can check it in `obj\...\formName.g.cs`).